# what is the probability that random shuffle of two deck of cards gives a k cards in the same position?

Tags: probability

> Two identical decks of cards, each containing $N$ cards, are shuffled
>   randomly. We say that a $k-matching$ occurs if the two decks agree in
>   exactly $k$ places. Show that the probability that there is a
>   $k-matching$ is  $$
>  \pi_k=\frac{1}{k!}(1-\frac{1}{1!}+\frac{1}{2!}-\frac{1}{3!}+...+\frac{(-1)^{N-k}}{(N-k)!})$$
>   for $k=0,1,2,...,N-1,N$. We note that $\pi _k \approx(k!e)^{-1}$.

So Here is my attempt: if we let $f_i$ denote the number of permutations of $i$ elements without fixing any elements.  Then $f_n=(n-1)!+\binom{n}{2}f_{n-2}$ for $n\geq5$, and  $f_1=0,f_2=1,f_3=2,f_4=9$. Hence $\pi_k=\frac{\binom{N}{k}f_{N-k}}{N!}$.

update:
I know see that number derangement of $N-k$ elements is $(N-k)!(1-\frac{1}{2!}+\frac{1}{3!}-\frac{1}{4!}+...+\frac{-1^{N-k}}{(N-k)!})$. and this solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Calculating $f_i$ is a good idea, however your formula is wrong [see WolframAlpha comparison](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=!7%3D(7-1)!%2BBinomial(7,2)*!5) .

After card $1\mapsto i$ was chosen, (you are right, n-1 possibilities) there is two cases: $i\mapsto 1$ and $i\not\mapsto 1$. Try deriving $f_i$ that way.

Also I would suggest $\pi_k=\frac{\binom{N}{k}f_{N-k}}{N!}$. Maybe it was also just a typo of yours.

If you calculate $f_i$ correctly, you actually get equality, (no $>$, ah I guess that's just a typo.)
( [Example with N=15](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Binomial(15,k)%2F15!*Subfactorial%5B-k%20%2B%2015%5D%3D1%2Fk!*Sum%5B(-1)%5Ei%2Fi!,%20%7Bi,%200,%20-k%20%2B%2015%7D%5D) )

Good luck on calculating the two equations.
Btw you can find the formula for $f_i$ on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement), so you can also check the answer that way.

Comment: hey thanks, I corrected the typos.